# How to resolve a vii°6 to root position I chord

Tags: voice-leading

When resolving a vii°6 chord to I6 I am allowed to resolve the D5 to a P5 but my book makes it clear not to do this if I am resolving the vii°6 to I in root position. Now today I was writing this progression and I got stuck on how to move to the I chord without going from a D5 to a P5. can someone help me out with how to write the next chords upper voices?
[image]

Comment: Make it an augmented fourth and resolve it to a perfect fourth?  Is that allowed?  Are you required to have an F in the fourth chord?

Comment: I can resolve it using an A4 to P4 but I wanted to do it this way. what if I had to do it this way? Would I just have to leave the F out of the I chord and have a 3 voice chord with a doubled root and 3rd?

Comment: "but I wanted to do it this way" perhaps the point of this exercise is to demonstrate that you can't do it this way with the rules you have at your disposal.  Something has to give, and the specific formulation of the rules with which you are working might specify what has to give.  For example, you might be forced by the rules to use a different voicing for the first right hand chord. Without changing the chords already written, you pretty much have to leave out the F in the fourth chord, with soprano and alto doubling the D, though I don't know whether your rules permit that.

Comment: Leaving out the 5th is what needs to be done then. Is it strange to resolve the chord this way? I see it done in my textbook but only in chorale style examples.

Comment: I don't suppose it's particularly strange, but I would avoid it if possible.  You haven't said what is given in this exercise, so I've been assuming the bass part and the Roman numerals.  Is that correct?

Comment: oh yes sorry.. this is my own exercise, I just wanted to know what my options were... your comments should be an answer so I could mark the questions solved

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good case where reducing the harmony to three parts is helpful for deciding what to do, and there aren't any seventh chord making four parts more necessary.

It's common to have `viio6` resolve to `I` with the fifth omitted. All tones move according to tendency: `TI DO`, `RE DO`, and `FA MI`...

[image]

Use your current voicing but remove the doubled tone and move all the voices the same way...

[image]

Now if you double the third of `viio6` (`RE`, `C4`) the question is how to move it. You don't want to move it the same as the `C3` in the bass, that will create parallel octaves. So move it up and double the third of `I`.

[image]

You might see rules that say to *not* double the third of a chord, but in fact I see doubled thirds in real classical scores enough to discount that rule as a fundamental.

> When resolving a vii°6 chord to I6 I am allowed to resolve the D5 to a P5 but my book makes it clear not to do this if I am resolving the vii°6 to I in root position.

I don't know exactly how your book states those particulars, but it bothers me to think that it's all stated as if it comes from a *single* notion of harmonic progression as chord to chord *resolutions*.

Dmitri Tymoczko presents an interesting idea of three systems of harmony in his [MUS 106 syllabus](https://dmitri.mycpanel.princeton.edu/files/pdfs/MUS106handouts.pdf) (I didn't take the class, but his syllabi are good reading.) The three systems are basically functional, fauxbourdon (parallel 6/3 chords, or bass scale harmonizations), and sequential harmony.

It seems clearer to me to distinguish `viio6 I6` as *parallel* 6/3 chord where voice leading and functional issues are basically irrelevant, and then only `viio6 I` is the time to be concerned about voice leading, tendencies, and resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Since the leading tone is in an inner voice, it can move downward to 5 rather than upward to 1.

The alto voice must move up to avoid a parallel octave with the bass.

Soprano moves up, so the resulting chord doubles scale degree 5.

Comment: This frustrates the resolution of *both* elements of the diminished fifth.  I would sooner double the third, especially if this is, as it appears to be, a keyboard piece, where doubling at the unison is indistinguishable from one voice dropping out.